Why does Haskell's type inference give these functions different type signatures?
I am a professor teaching Haskell in a programming languages class. We are covering partial application and currying. So, I gave the following example functions:
multThenAdd x y z = (x * y) + z

multBy5ThenAdd y z = (5 * y) + z
multBy5ThenAdd' y z = multThenAdd 5 y z
multBy5ThenAdd'' = multThenAdd 5

I expected the last three functions to have the same type signature when I ran them through Haskell's type inference in GHCi. The first two gave the type signature I expected, but the third did not:
*Main> :t multBy5ThenAdd
multBy5ThenAdd :: Num a => a -> a -> a
*Main> :t multBy5ThenAdd'
multBy5ThenAdd' :: Num a => a -> a -> a
*Main> :t multBy5ThenAdd''
multBy5ThenAdd'' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer

Why did Haskell decide that the parameters and return value had to be Integer for the last function? If I give it an explicit type signature, it compiles fine and then works on any type in the Num typeclass as expected.

It only works that way in GHCi, due to defaulting. If you compile it as part of a program, the type will be generic.

The dreaded monomorphism restriction. Enabled by default in GHC, disabled by default in GHCi. It's a wart, a special case in the type system, with some benefits, but still a wart. Just disable it if you want a more regular system. Or provide explicit type signatures.

Defaulting is the reason you get Integer, but the reason you get a different type in the first place is indeed the monomorphism restriction.

@FyodorSoikin I believe it's actually the opposite; the monomorphism restriction has been disabled by default in GHCi for a long time, so if these functions had been defined at the GHCi prompt they would all be polymorphic, whereas multBy5ThenAdd'' will be given a monomorphic type when compiked as part of a module. (From the formatting clues it looks like they may have been defined in a file and then loaded into GHCi to be checked with :t)
